# Chrome and Firefox are cancelling my local requests

Tags: javascript, selenium, flash

I'm trying to test some local flash development by injecting my swf file into the website being served up by my test server.

I've already set `--disable-web-security` on Chrome to allow me to load local resources.

On FireFox I've set:

```
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy = false
security.checkloaduri = false
```

In both cases my code is failing.  Here is what my markup looks like:

```
<object style="visibility: visible;" id="flash_test" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="640"
height="480">
  <param name="movie" value="file:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/Test.swf" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="menu" value="false" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="type" value="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
  <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
  <embed id="flash_test" src="file:///C:/Users/Peter/Desktop/Test.swf" allowscriptaccess="always" menu="false"
  quality="high" width="640" height="480" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

In the Chrome developer tools Test.swf shows as Status Canceled.
In FireFox it doesn't even show that the browser attempted to load the Flash file, it is completely absent form the Network list.

In both browsers there is no Console message of any kind showing.

My goal is to automate this with Selenium in the future, so I'd prefer to avoid a plugin, unless it will work with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your html code.  Its absolutely correct.

Make sure following:-

1. Flash players installed and enabled
2. swf must exist at the path given.
3. Try another simple swf. (to make sure the swf is correct and nothing wrong with swf itself)

Comment: I tried copying the above object html block and pasting it into the body of an empty body tag; saved it locally to the same folder as the swf file.  It ran successfully in both browsers with no other changes of any kind.